# how to get the response from the php page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to send the textbox value on anchor tag click to checkID.php and display the response sent from php page in html page. I tried using javascripts. But the page is redirected to checkID.php page. need to display in the very same html page.

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:fillContent('checkID.php'); ">
    Check Availability
</a>
```

In form action I speceified as checkID.php.
Following is the javascript I used

```
<script language="javascript">
    function fillContent(resource)
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("POST", resource, true);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
                el = document.getElementById('availabilityResponse')
                el.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
</script>
```

below is my php code

```
<?php    
require_once('lib/nusoap.php'); 
$client=new nusoap_client("http://localhost/server.php?wsdl"); 
$error = $client->getError();
if ($error) {
     return $error;
}
$alias=$_POST['id'];
$response = $client->call("checkAvailability", array("id" => $alias));
 if($client->fault)  
 {  
    return $client->faultstring;  
 }  
else 
 {  
    $error = $client->getError();
    if ($error) {
       return $error;
    }
    else {
        return $response;
         }
 }
?>
```

how to get response and display in html page?

Comment: be more specific, what you want?

Comment: can you show your complete HTML code ?

Comment: I need to display the response from the php code. this is my php code

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why its getting redirected, but in your PHP file -

Instead of

```
return $response;
```

Use

```
echo $response;
```

Always use `echo` instead of `return` in ajax cases

Comment: is it still getting redirected ?

Comment: @anto - Did you change your `return` to `echo` in your error handling as well? They all need to be `echo`.

Comment: @SachynKosare page is not redirected. but the response is not shown

Comment: if you use firebug then check the reponse or simply `alert(xmlhttp.responseText)` to see what you are getting from server

Answer (score 0):

That code should not redirect to that page.  Cancel the click action and see if that helps.

```
 onclick="fillContent('checkID.php');return false"
```

Comment: Thanks. I used it and the page is not redirected. But the return value from the php code is not displayed

Comment: My guess is it is returning an error and not a success. Add a error method and see if it gets called.

Comment: I have used error method. I have posted my php script. Can you check whether its correct?

Comment: So was it called? What is the error message. Look at the Ajax request in your console log /network tab. Debug it.

Comment: @anto - Mix this answer with `@Sachyn's` and you should sort your issue.

Comment: @epascarello it shows "object expected" in the ajax script first line

Comment: @anto Put your ajax script at the bottom of the page (just before the `</body>` tag), or in case you are already using jquery, put the script in `$(document).ready` (http://api.jquery.com/ready/) and use jquery ajax which is much simpler (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use jquery. Its very simple

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#myID").on("click",function(){
$.ajax({ url: 'checkID.php',
                                        type: 'post',
                                        success: function(output) {
                                                   $("#availabilityResponse").html(output);
                                                 }
                                    });
})

</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:;" id="myID" ">Check Availability</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing is displayed when I click Check Availability

Comment: check whether ajax call is happening or not. You can see it in the browsers console

Comment: Error while running in console. 'Object expected' on line $("myID").on("click",function(){